# How to do customized group by in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table :

```
ID     TYPE     AMOUNT
--     ----     ------
 1     sell         50
 1     sell        100
 1      buy        200
 2     sell         50
 2      buy        100
```

How do I write a SQL query that returns the following result:

```
ID    TOTAL
--    -----
 1       50
 2       50
```

I think I need a `group by id` but am not sure about how to do a "subtract" on the "sell" ones.

My db is oracle, btw.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: thanks, Ashwin. that is better looking! how do u do that btw?

Comment: Accessdenier: formatting help (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) To make something look like code, add four spaces before each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
select "id",sum(decode(type,'sell',-"amount","amount")) total
from table1
group by "id"
```

[**SQL FIDDLE OUTPUT**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45c78/6/0)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple.

```
SELECT id, SUM(
       CASE type
         WHEN 'Buy' THEN amount
         WHEN 'Sell' THEN -amount
       END
       ) AS TOTAL
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
```